# SQL: Distinct count with where?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my table:

Players_Games_Table

```
MDATE   PLAYER  TEAM
12      evra    liverpool
12      giggs   liverpool
12      smith   liverpool
13      evra    leeds
13      giggs   liverpool
13      smith   manu
14      evra    spurs
14      giggs   liverpool
14      smith   chelsea
```

I want to return the players name (PLAYER) of players who have played for "liverpool" and at least one other team.

Something like this:

```
select distinct player, count(team) from stats
where team = 'liverpool'
group by player
having count(team) > 1;
```

Comment: _WHERE_ comes before _GROUP BY_

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers (e.g. columns having odd names.) Use single quotes for string literals.

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT, your GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done in several ways, for example you can have a correlated sub-query that performs the team counting:

```
select *
from
(
    select player, (select count(distinct team) from stats s2
                    where s2.player = s1.player) as teamcount
    from stats s1
    where team = 'Liverpool'
) dt
where teamcount > 1
```

Or, a standard `GROUP BY`, combined with `EXISTS`:

```
select player, count(distinct team)
from stats s1
where exists (select * from stats s2
              where s1.player = s2.player
                and s2.team = 'Liverpool')
group by player
having count(distinct team) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.PLAYER,count(*)+1 
from stats a 
join stats b
on (a.PLAYER=b.PLAYER)
where a.TEAM=liverpool and b.TEAM!=liverpool
group by a.PLAYER;
```